# Validate optional mandatory fields in MVC5

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model, AddSpecificitiesViewModel, with the following values:

```
 public class AddSpecificitiesViewModel
 {
    public bool? Elevator { get; set; }
    public string ElevatorCapacity { get; set; }
 }
```

Another model clientViewModel:

```
 public class clientViewModel
 {
     public AddSpecificitiesViewModel add {get; set;}
 }
```

Both properties Elevator and ElevatorCapacity of the AddSpecificitiesViewModel are mandatory but ElevatorCapacity is filled only if Elevator is set to true.
  How can I validate a model of this type?

For example, if I Elevator is true and I have not filled ElevatorCapacity in the form, how to I validate the model in the controller?

```
 public ActionResult Client(ClientViewModel clientViewModel)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid){
        //action
    } else {
       //action
    }
        return View("Index", clientViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like it would be best to have an `Elevator` class with a mandatory capacity. Then the `Elevator` property in your `AddSpecificitiesViewModel` could be optional (so null or a reference to an instance of `Elevator`). I think that's better than having "co-mandatory" properties.

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute - e.g. a [fooproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[RequiredIf]`(or you can use [this one](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-conditionalvalidation). And if you want to learn to write your own, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: I didn't read whole thing yet, but that property names though, why is your boolean property called `Elevator` and why is capacity `string`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  Can I use this for MVC5?

Comment: @SeM : Client requirements

Comment: @tabby, Yes you can.

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  What if I use fluent validations on the AddSpecificitiesViewModel ?  Something like RuleFor(obj => obj.add .ElevatorCapacity).NotEmpty().WithLocalizedMessage(typeof(BString), "Error").Unless(obj => obj.add .Elevator.Equals(true));?

Comment: That will not give you client side validation (`.Unless()` and many other conditional rules are not supported on the client)

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  I have another question, in the clientViewModel I want two AddSpecificitiesViewModel, one for departure the other for destination and another string, Type.  If type="Dep", then only the departure AddSpecificitiesViewModel will be displayed and the destination one will not.  How can I validate this using fluentValidation?

Comment: If you have another question, then ask another question :)